# Trying to log into an authenticated website

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to log into a web page and access an authenticated page. It isn't working.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://www.thomsononeim.com/s-log_in.asp")
br.select_form(name="MainForm")
br.form['txtLoginID'] = 'Username'
br.form['txtPWD'] = 'Password'
br.submit()
```

EDIT: I believe the issue is trying to log into a JavaScript page.

Comment: Simply submitting the form is not enough. You must also handle the returned cookie or other token. Save and return it with subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib` and submit post parameters.
Ex:

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import urllib.request as urlreq

params = urlparse.urlencode({'txtLoginId':'Username', 'txtPWD':'Password'})

req = urlreq.urlopen("http://www.your-site.com/login.php", params)
page = str(req.read())
```

`page` is now a string wich contains source code of the authenticated page.